# C - send() is not working when assigning a value in a switch statement

Tags: c

This is a basic program that talks to a server. It asks the client to enter either R, P, or S and then it will send the response (1, 2, or 3). The server will make its own decision, receive the players decision, and calculate a winner and then send the winner back.

Here is my code for sending it from the client to the server.

```
 char choice[1];
bool done = false;
while (!done) {
    printf("Rock = R , Paper = P, and Scissors = S\n");
    printf("Enter your choice:");
    scanf("%s", decision);

    switch (decision[0]) {
        case 'R' :
            decision[0] = '\0';
            choice[0] = '1';
            done = true;
            break;

        case 'P' :
            decision[0] = '\0';
            choice[0] = '2';
            done = true;
            break;

        case 'S' :
            decision[0] = '\0';
            choice[0] = '3';
            done = true;
            break;

        default :
            decision[0] = '\0';
            printf("That is not a correct entry. Please try again.\n");

    }
}

char *sendChoice = &choice[0];
//*((char*)choice) = '1';
printf("Player Choice: %c\n", *sendChoice);

if (send(clientSocket, sendChoice, strlen(sendChoice), 0) < 0){
printf("send error\n");
}
```

No matter what I do, I keep getting a send error. I have tried everything I can think. I searched online for anything that can help and I simply cannot figure out why it doesn't work.

If I comment out the switch and while loop and simply hard code the client choice it will work, so it must have something to do with the switch statement.

I should note that the connection is working. Its simply the send function that does not work.

Comment: Full code please so we can reproduce it?

Comment: You're using `strlen` to determine how  many bytes to send, but you're not null-terminating `choice`, and in fact you're declaring `choice` as an array of size 1, so there isn't even room for a null byte. Also, if you're only ever expecting to be sending a single byte, don't use `strlen`. Just hard-code the amount as 1.

Comment: Just hard-code `1` as the length to send, rather than calling `strlen()`.

Comment: You assign the same value to `decision[0]` in every case. Why does it need to be inside the `switch`?

Comment: In the case of an error you really should print out what the actual error is. See the man page for `send()` https://linux.die.net/man/3/send and the man page for `perror()`  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_perror.htm

Comment: I did have it hardcoded as 1 but it didn't work either.

Comment: Why is `choice` an array rather than just `char choice`?

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to send it as a single char so opted to use an array instead. I just printed out the error and it returned "Error: : Socket operation on non-socket"

Comment: That error is pretty self explanatory. The variable `clientSocket` does not have a valid socket handle in it. You need to provide the source code for the way that the socket is opened. In the case of errors, you need to print what the errors are.

Answer (score 0):

The `strlen` function is only for strings. In your code, `choice` is an array of one character, not a string. And `sendChoice` is a pointer to that single character.

The data length is one. You can just pass `1` as the size or you can use `sizeof(choice)`. Do not use `sizeof(sendChoice)` as that would be the size of the pointer! You cannot use `strlen` because you do not have a string.

If you think about it, there is no way `strlen` could tell just from the pointer you passed to it that it only pointed to a single character. So `strlen` could only work by some kind of magic.

Also, check the documentation for `send`. It will tell you how to get a useful error code when `send` fails that will help you troubleshoot in the future.